# Regex: shortest path not respected

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I want to parse something like this:

```
{{word1|word2|word3|word4|...}}
{{word1|word2|word3}}
...
```

with `preg_match_all`.
I just need the 3 first words, so I made this regex:

```
/\{\{(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)[\|.*]?\}\}/Uim
```

But when there are 4 words or more, the third capturing group takes `word3|word4|...`

I expected the `U` modifier to take the shortest path, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Can someone help me please ?

Comment: You could always just match the delimiting `{{` and `}}`, and use `explode()` on `|` with `$limit = 3`.

Comment: Well, I already thought about it, but I'm sure Regex(es) can do it faster, in a single operation. Anyway, great comment.

Comment: Regex solution will almost never be faster than native functions like explode()

Comment: Yes, but one regex + one native > one regex, am I right ? (it depends of the string, of course)

Comment: @ldiqual - The `U` modifier is _never_ needed or warranted. When you need to make a quantifier lazy, just append the `?` lazy modifier to the quantifier that needs it. But you don't need any lazy quantifiers here, what you need is a more accurate and precise expression. Hint: Instead of using: `(.*)` use: `([^|{}]*)` (and get rid of that completely useless `U` modifier!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility:

```
\{\{([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)(?:\||\}\})
```

Explanation:

```
\{\{          # Two of {{ 
([^|]*)       # Any characters until '|'
\|            # Character '|'
([^|]*)       # Any characters until '|'
\|            # Character '|'
([^|]*)       # Any characters until '|'
(?:\||\}\})   # A vertical bar, or two }}, without grouping.
```

Comment: It worked like a charm, except that the last `([^|]*)` is running to the next `{{ }}` block. I solved it by adding the `U` modifier. The final regex is: `/\{\{([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)(?:\||\}\})/U`. Thanks !

Comment: The expression `([^|]*)` allows matching the closing brace. A much improved expression would be: `([^|}]*)`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
/^\{\{([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)/im
```

`.*` takes `|` too so it matches `word1|word2...`

**edit:**

better version:

```
preg_match_all('/^{{([^|}]+)\|([^|}]+)\|([^|}]+)/m', "{{word1|word2|word3|word4|...}}\n{{word5|word6|word7}}", $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
var_dump($matches)
```

Comment: I only get partial results: `word1, word2, w`

Comment: `/^\{\{([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+).*\}\}/im` would give better results. Note no `U` modifier and `.*` at the end. But if I were you I would just strip the braces, than split the string by `|` and then take first three elements.

Comment: You need to remove `U` modifier if you want to get full word because `U` makes `+` ungreedy

Answer (score 1):

Try this here

```
/\{\{([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*).*\}\}/
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vh0f)

Since you don't search for letters, so you don't need the modifier `i`, no anchors `^` or `$` so no modifier `m` is needed. I used here `[^|]` which is ungreedy by design, so no `U` needed.